# How to specify multiple package names for service classes in REST web service using Jersey

Tags: servlets, jersey, jax-rs, web.xml

How do I specify multiple `<param-value>` for a given `<param-name>` under servlet's `<init-param>` tag. Following is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>com.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The parameter **jersey.config.server.provider.packages** defines in which package Jersey will look for the web service classes.

I want to specify multiple package names here, as my service classes are in different packages. Something like following, but none of them works:

1) Multiple `<param-value>`

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
    <param-value>com.vogella.jersey.second</param-value>
</init-param>
```

2) Multiple `<init-param>`

```
<servlet>
    ...
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.vogella.jersey.second</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: FYI, the scanning is recursive. i.e. `com.vogella.jersey` will scan both the above packages

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't specify multiple `<param-value>` for a single `<param-name>`.

Use this instead:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.pack.first;com.pack.rest.second</param-value>
</init-param>
```

`;` and `,` can be used as a separators.

Comment: +1 Perfect, thanks. Could you please suggest which tutorials can I follow/read to get more details like this? Would this be covered under Servlet tutorials?

Comment: @Learner Best place is [the Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html)

Comment: @Learner  https://www.youtube.com/user/koushks/playlists , there are 2 excellent playlists here for jax-rs.

Comment: what if I want to include all packages ?

Comment: what if I want to include packages as well as classes for <param-name>?

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Ramanlfc's answer, you can use "," as package separator too. For example:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.pkg.first,com.pkg.second</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Tested under Ubuntu 16.04.2, tomcat-8.5.11

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for you to specify multiple package names for service classes in REST web service using Jersey. In addition to the answer that mentioned by Ramanlfc, `\n` also works.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.demo1.resources
            com.demo2.resources
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```