# RESTEasy (jax-rs), multiple packages declaration in web.xml?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy, wildfly-8

How to declare multiple packages in the web.xml for the RESTEasy jax-rs provider?

If I have:

[image]

```
 <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
        <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
            <param-value>/rest</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class> org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher </servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
                <param-value>part1.MessageApplication</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

It's working.

But If I have :

[image]

And then change the declaration of the web.xml (which is based on [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234427/how-to-specify-multiple-package-names-for-service-classes-in-rest-web-service-us), which may have already worked in Jersey)

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>part1.MessageApplication;part2.MessageApplication2</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
```

Whenever I try to access a `@Path`*-mapped-class* in package "`part2`" it will throw :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: part1.MessageApplication;part2.MessageApplication2 from
```

Note that I'm aware that I've changed the `@Path`-mapped-class with different url path like `@Path("controller2")`.

How do I configure it properly in the `web.xml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I clearly understand your problem. The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37234427/1426227) you provided in your question is about specifying multiple packages. But looks like you are dealing with two [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) subclasses. It's a different matter.

In this situation, you should register two `HttpServletDispatcher` mapped to different URI patterns, as following:

```xml
<!-- Application 1 (part1.MessageApplication) mapped to /rest/app1/* -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-application1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>part1.MessageApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-application1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/app1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Application 2 (part2.MessageApplication2) mapped to /rest/app2/* -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-application2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>part2.MessageApplication2</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-application2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/app2/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Each [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) subclass is mapped to a path that serves as the base URI for the resource URIs provided by [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation.

You could have multiple [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) subclasses when you support multiple versions of the API, for example. For simple applications, it's very likely you don't need that.

### You may not need a `web.xml`

As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511644/resteasy-jax-rs-multiple-packages-declaration-in-web-xml/43513823#comment74082340_43513823), you are using WildFly 8. It's Servlet 3.0 compatible so you don't even need a `web.xml` deployment descriptor for simple applications. Most of the configurations, such as registering servlets, filters and listeners can be done via annotations.

In case you are not providing a `web.xml` deployment descriptor for your Maven-based web application project, you need to configure your [`maven-war-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) to ignore the missing `web.xml` file by setting the [`failOnMissingWebXml`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#failOnMissingWebXml) configuration property to `false` in your project `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Since the version 3.0.0 of the [`maven-war-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/), the default value for [`failOnMissingWebXml`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#failOnMissingWebXml) has been changed from `true` to `false`. You can use the most recent version and ommit that configuration property.

If, for some reason, you want to keep the `web.xml`, it can be as simple as:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">

</web-app>
```

### A few words on the `Application` class

Regarding JAX-RS, annotate your [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) subclass with [`@ApplicationPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) specifying the base URI for your resource classes:

```java
@ApplicationPath("api")
public SampleApplication extends Application {

}
```

In the example above, the JAX-RS runtime will scan the classpath for JAX-RS components and will register them automatically.

If you want to manually register your resources and providers (preventing the JAX-RS runtime from registering the components automatically), override the [`getClasses()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getClasses--) and/or the [`getSingletons()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getSingletons--) methods:

```java
@ApplicationPath("api")
public SampleApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        resources.add(MyResource.class);
        resources.add(MyOtherResource.class);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

For more details on the [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) class, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42077836/1426227) can provide you some insights.

### Managing your dependencies

It's worthwhile to mention that [RESTEasy 3.x is shipped with WildFly](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/11/WildFly8-Final-Released/). If you will use only the JAX-RS API the following dependency will give you all you need:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you need to use any type from the RESTEasy API, add the RESTEasy 3.x dependencies with the `provided` scope. It tells Maven that the container will provide that dependency, hence they won't be shipped with your application. Failing to provide the right scope may cause some weird errors and bad headaches. For more details on scopes, check the [dependency scope documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Comment: Thanks, btw, ya that's exactly what my question is `2 Application subclasses` *in different packages*, btw since I'm newbie in jax-rs overall, do you use only single `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` for across multiple controllers/services, or just use one? .I'll try your suggestion later, i'm outside now.

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup It depends on what you are trying to achieve. I usually have multiple `Application` subclasses when I am supporting multiple versions of the API, for example. For simple applications, you don't need that. Each `Application` subclass is mapped to a path that serves as the base URI for all resource URIs provided by `@Path` annotation.

Comment: Btw If I recall I've tried that before for the rest of my life, but somehow it behaves different in RESTEasy.

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup What container are you using?

Comment: Wildfly 8.0.., with single dependency `resteasy-jaxrs-2.2-1.GA.jar`, though, i must admit, the container itself is kinna painful :D

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup You don't even need a `web.xml` for deploying web applications in WildFly 8. It's Servet 3.x compatible.

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup For more details on the `Application` class, refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42077836/1426227). I will update my answer with some details that can point you to a good direction.